# Javascript to type "alt" from image url omitting specific characters

Tags: javascript, replace, alt

The following script works but not as expected.

```
<img class="img" src="https://photoooo.com/Name-Name2.jpg" width="200" height="300" />
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('img').each(function(){  
   var $img = $(this);
   var filename = $img.attr('src')  
     if (typeof attr == typeof undefined || attr == false){
        $img.attr('alt', filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1, filename.lastIndexOf('.')));
    }  
  });  
 });
```

I would like to modify the script so that it fetches the name of the photo to "alt" from the url of the photo. Excluding characters: "-" and ".jpg".

Answer (score 0):

use the `replace` method to remove the specific characters from the filename before setting it as the alt attribute

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('img').each(function(){  
    var $img = $(this);
    var filename = $img.attr('src')  
    if (typeof attr == typeof undefined || attr == false){
    console.log(filename)
        var altText = filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1, filename.lastIndexOf('.'))
        altText = altText.replace("-", "").replace(".jpg", "")
        $img.attr('alt', altText);
        console.log(altText)
    }  
  });  
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <img class="img" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/01/15/40/internationalwomensday-2108838_960_720.png" width="200" height="300" />
```

Comment: Did not work. It downloads with these characters I don't want :(

Comment: It's work fine, please Run Code Snipped

Comment: Yes, it works elegantly. Sorry for the confusion.